# How to stop Runaway Perl Process

Tags: perl

I'm on a Linux PC.  I inadvertantly created a PERL script with endless recursion: subroutine A calls subroutine B which calls A, which calls B, etc.

I want to stop these, but I don't want to reboot.  How can I do it?

If I try to kill the Process IDs, and there's 900 of them, by the time that finishes, there's hundreds more.

Comment: *endless recursion: subroutine A calls subroutine B which calls A, which calls B, etc* will not create any new process so there is probably something missing in the story.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil is right, unless your subroutines call `fork`.

Answer (score 3):

perhaps you can use `killall` to kill all of the running processes by name:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall

Comment: Yeah, `killall perl` ought to do it.